# Efficient multithreaded shared access to memory buffer

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

This question might be pretty simple but still I can't figure out an efficient way to do this. I have the following setup:

1) Thread A constantly downloads data from the internet into a memory buffer.

2) At the same time, thread B wants to read data that has already been downloaded from this buffer.

The buffer is not circular or anything. There is a write cursor and a read cursor. Once thread A has written something to the buffer, it updates the write cursor to tell thread B how much data is currently available for reading.

The problem is that thread B often reads thousands of bytes but in steps of just a single byte at a time. Thus I need an efficient way of synchronizing the two threads. I've already tried SetEvent() and WaitForSingleObject() but that seems quite slow (or I did something wrong) because thread B is reading in packets of 1 byte from the buffer so thread B has to call WaitForSingleObject() for every byte it needs to read. Sounds like a lot of overhead.

Shouldn't it be possible to do this without any mutex (critical section) protection? i.e. thread B could just poll the write cursor until enough data is available and then copy it. But then the question of synchronization comes up, i.e. when thread A updates the write cursor, is this change immediately reflected in thread B? I don't have much experience with multithreading programming and many of the articles available on it sound extremely complicated so I'd be glad if somebody could point me into the right direction to implement this in an efficient way.

Comment: Try very hard to not do this.  Data is typically read from networks in chunks that are much larger than one byte.  Do you really have to use just one buffer?  Why can thread A read a big chunk into a dynamically-allocated buffer struct/instance, queue off, (blocking producer-consumer queue), the buffer pointer to thread B and immediately allocate a new buffer for the next load of data?  Inter-thread comms for single bytes is grossly inefficient, no matter how you do it.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm doing now: Reading in packets of 16kb from the stream thread and buffering these packets for fast byte-based access from the main program. This is efficient and a better approach then polling.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can poll in one thread for changes made in the other thread, without needing a mutex. This is very fast, but has high CPU overhead as thread B constantly polls to check for new data.

Comment: But is the data synchronized immediately? I remotely remember that changes made to a variable in thread A might not be immediately available to thread B. AFAIR synchronization only takes place every once in a while or when doing a Sleep(0) or something like that but I might be wrong here.

Comment: Depending on your CPU... But decent CPUs will have immediate synchronization.